# PyQt5 can not installed AttributeError: module 'sipbuild.api' has no attribute 'prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel'

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have found tons of "solutions" on Google, but none of them actually work.

My env:

- macOS
- Python 3.9
- pip 22.0.3

I have tried lowering pip or upgrading pip, and fixing version of PyQt5, but the error still exists.

```
 line 156, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          hook = backend.prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
      AttributeError: module 'sipbuild.api' has no attribute 'prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel'
```

Comment: Can you include the full stack trace, please? That looks like it's only the last part of it.